# Microsoft word 2010 Table of content formatting issue

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

[image]

My table of content is screwed up. The screen shot shows Chapter 4 in page 29 and Summary on page 30. But the page 30 does not have the series of dots on it. I tried re-recreating the TOC and also tried recreating the 4.1 header but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain what is this line **"page 30 does not have the series of dots on it."**?

Comment: You see that second line which says "4.1 Summary 30". "30" is the page number. That should align to the number page 29 at the end of the  first line. So I was expecting something like "4.1 Summary..............................30".

Answer (score 4):

I can give you two options:

### Option 1: Reset all styles

This is the easier method. You will, however, lose all custom styling. Make sure to save before doing this.

On the Home tab, click Change Styles > Style Set > Word 2010

### Option 2: Change TOC 2 style

You can manually edit the TOC 2 style. It might also be another TOC #, TOC 2 is used by default for level 2 headers.

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S to open the Styles dock.
2. Right click on the appropriate style (TOC 2). You may wish to see the correct one (TOC 1) to compare. If you cannot find the style, click Options in the bottom right of the Styles dock and "Select styles to show:" "All styles".
3. Select Modify.
4. Click Format on the bottom left of the Modify Style window and select Tabs.
5. Select Alignment Right and the dotted Leader.
   You may have to play around with those options a bit.